# Jumi Search Plugin

Tags: joomla1.5, jumi

My Joomla 1.5 site default search is working fine, but it is not searching for Jumi contents of the site. I know the Jumi contents are dynamic and hard to get searched by the default search. Now I want to know how can I create a plugin to include the Jumi search results?